# How to bind jQuery to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Apologies for a newbie question that's probably not phrased very well.

I am trying to work with this example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc-4/

It uses Enter country name @Html.TextBox("Country") to select the country name, and I can populate this, but I can't figure out how to bind this to a model with something like TextBoxFor so that I can post the data back to the controller.

Comment: What MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using FormCollection form in Action. By using formCollection you can access the form elements in the controller.
But for this you have to modify your code, you have to add Form to your view.
Provide name property to the Country textbox.

Comment: Refer this code...


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection collection)
{
    string countryName= Convert.ToString(collection["txt-Country"]);
    //Code
    return View();`enter code here
}